# Fast enumeration ordering

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, fast-enumeration

Do

```
for (id object in array) {
    // do something with object
}
```

guarantee to return the objects in the order they are put in the array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's just shorthand for an enumerator. So **yes** for `NSArray`s, **no** for `NSSet`s and `NSDictionary`s

Comment: But thats only because NSSets and NSDictionaries are hash tables and thus are by design unordered.